# How to colorize "root" in red in CentOS?

Tags: centos, colors, bashrc

This is the content of /etc/bashrc, I would like to modify it for show "root" as red but don't know where to add the color code.

```
# /etc/bashrc

# System wide functions and aliases
# Environment stuff goes in /etc/profile

# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
        fi
        ;;
    screen)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
        ;;
      esac
  fi
  # Turn on checkwinsize
  shopt -s checkwinsize
  [ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
  # You might want to have e.g. tty in prompt (e.g. more virtual machines)
  # and console windows
  # If you want to do so, just add e.g.
  # if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  #   PS1="[\u@\h:\l \W]\\$ "
  # fi
  # to your custom modification shell script in /etc/profile.d/ directory
fi

if ! shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're not a login shell
    # Need to redefine pathmunge, it get's undefined at the end of /etc/profile
    pathmunge () {
        case ":${PATH}:" in
            *:"$1":*)
                ;;
            *)
                if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                    PATH=$PATH:$1
                else
                    PATH=$1:$PATH
                fi
        esac
    }

    # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
    # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
    # You could check uidgid reservation validity in
    # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
    if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
       umask 002
    else
       umask 022
    fi

    # Only display echos from profile.d scripts if we are no login shell
    # and interactive - otherwise just process them to set envvars
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
        if [ -r "$i" ]; then
            if [ "$PS1" ]; then
                . "$i"
            else
                . "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
            fi
        fi
    done

    unset i
    unset pathmunge
fi
# vim:ts=4:sw=4
```

In Debian I do it in this line:
`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00;37m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[01;37m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]\w\[\033[01;35m\]\$\[\033[00m\] '`
but in CentOS no idea.

edit: Also I am thinking that maybe editing that file is going to take effect on both normal user and root user. But looking in the specifics .bashrc they only point to /etc/bashrc.

Comment: I'm guessing `$USER` is being used in place of `\u` there ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to play with the colours, but something like this should do the trick.  Create the file /etc/profile.d/colours.sh with content similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 >/dev/null  2>&1 ]; then
  export PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00;37m\]@\h:\w\$ "
fi
```

Comment: You could also just put the `PS1` declaration in `/root/.bashrc`.  Also, red is color 31.

Comment: ok I got it. Instead of declaring PS1 in `/etc/bashrc` I did it on the specifics `/home/user/.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc`, and the parameters of PS1 were the same as I have on Debian. That's it `"\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00;37m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[01;37m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]\w\[\033[01;35m\]\$\[\033[00m\] "` for normal user and `"\[\033[01;31m\]\u\[\033[00;37m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[01;37m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]\w\[\033[01;35m\]\$\[\033[00m\] "` for root.

Comment: To ensure that `\u` and `\h` and `\w` and friends resolve correctly, one should enclose the value for `PS1` in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Add in `~/.bashrc`

```
 export PS1='\[\e[31;1m\]\h\w # \[\e[0m\]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to my `~/.bash_profile` on a Mac OSX Sierra. It would be `~/.bashrc` in Ubuntu.

`export SUDO_PS1="\[\e[31;1m\]$PS1\[\e[0m\]"`